# Combination of two regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression

I'm using form validator in order to validate some fields on my signup form. One of which is a telephone field for which I have prepared two regexes that will provide validation.

```
regexp: {
regexp: 
>/(^01|^02|^071|^073|^074|^075|^076|^077|^078|^079)/, 
         /^((?!(012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|0{6,}|1{6,}|2{6,}|3{6,}|4{6,}|5{6,}|6{6,}|7{6,}|8{6,}|9{6,})).)*$/

message: 'The phone number is not valid'
                    }
```

My issue is that only one of those two will work, not both. Any idea how I could modify this such that they both work?

Comment: "only one of those two will work, not both" - do you mean you can only use one regular expression or that one of them does not do what you want it to do (which? why?)?

Comment: Holy hell that is complicated... maybe simplifying it would make your problem go away

Comment: Yes, only one will work inside the validation @user5288

Comment: @RyanJ  It's not that compliacted....

Comment: @user2713650 which is a matter of opinion... there's a lot of repeated sequence and inefficiencies that make what you're doing more complicated than it probably needs to be. Why don't you elaborate more on what your intended validation criteria is and then ask for help? Generally speaking, what I mean is phone number validation just checks to make sure the number meets a specific format, not that the number itself, if you called it, was valid.

Comment: The first bit checks to ensure the number begins with either 01, 02, 071, 074, 075, 075, 077, 078 or 079. The second checks to ensure there doesn't exist a sequence of consecutive numbers from 0 to 9 of length 6, nor does there exist a sequence of consecutive numbers of itself of length 6 @RyanJ

Comment: For this purpose, matching substrings against a hash might be faster than using regex's. But  /^0(?:[12]|7[145789])/ is a shorter match for your first set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work, but I'd still suggest maybe finding a different way or set of criteria to validate. It's up to you though.

```
/^(0(?:[12]|7[145789]))(?!012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|0{6,}|1{6,}|2{6,}|3{6,}|4{6,}5{6,}|6{6,}|7{6,}|8{6,}|9{6,})/
```

This will ensure the number begins with the proper prefix and does not contain the sequences you've indicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Lol I'm specifically being told it has to be this way unfortunately - it won't allow me to vote up but many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the two like this:

```
/^(?=(01|02|071|073|074|075|076|077|078|079))((?!(012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|0{6,}|1{6,}|2{6,}|3{6,}|4{6,}|5{6,}|6{6,}|7{6,}|8{6,}|9{6,})).)*$/
```

Does seem like a kind of obfuscated way to perform some fairly simple checks to me, but to each their own.